# Guess the number: How many guesses for computer to get correct number?

Tags: c++, math

I'm very new to C++, and programming in general. I decided that I wanted to make a "Guess the Number" game, but I wanted see how many guesses on average it would take the computer to guess a number between 1 and 10,000,000.

The easiest way that I could think of finding the "secret" number was to
1. take the range and divide it by two(**divisor**) and that would be the guess.

a. if the guess is greater than the "secret" number, then the guess-1 becomes the new maximum of the     range, and I go back to step 1.
b. if the guess is lower than the "secret" number, then the guess+1 becomes the new minimum of the range and I go back to step 1.

This repeats until the number is found. From my experience, it takes the computer 22 guesses to guess the "secret" number.

For fun, I wanted to see what would happen if I changed the divisor. I was actually a bit surprised by the results for 1,000,000 iterations of trying to guess the number between 1 and 10,000,000 for a range of divisors from 2 to 10.

```
Average with divisor 2 is 22.3195
Average with divisor 3 is 20.5549
Average with divisor 4 is 20.9087
Average with divisor 5 is 22.0998
Average with divisor 6 is 23.1571
Average with divisor 7 is 25.5232
Average with divisor 8 is 25.927
Average with divisor 9 is 27.1941
Average with divisor 10 is 28.0839
```

I would love to understand why when the divisors 3, 4, and 5, are used the computer is able to, on average, use less guesses to find the "secret" number.

My code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int half_search(int a, int b, int n, int m)
{
    int aMax = b;
    int aMin = a;
    int divisor = m;
    int result;
    static int counter = 0;
    double guess = ((static_cast<double>(b) - a) / divisor) + aMin;

    if(guess - static_cast<int>(guess) >= 0.5)
        guess = ceil(guess);

    if(guess < n)
    {
        aMin = guess + 1;
        counter++;
        half_search(aMin, aMax, n, divisor);
    }
    else if(guess > n)
    {
        aMax = guess - 1;
        counter++;
        half_search(aMin, aMax, n, divisor);
    }
    else
    {
        counter++;
        result = counter;
        counter = 0;
        return result;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int MIN = 1;
    const int MAX = 10000000;
    int k = 0;
    int j = 2; //represents lowest divisor
    int l = 10; //represent highest divisor
    int iterations = 100000;
    double stepSum = 0;
    vector<int> myVector(iterations);

    srand(1);
    while(j <=10)
    {
        while(k < iterations)
        {
            int n = rand() % MAX + 1;

            myVector[k] = half_search(MIN, MAX, n, j);

            stepSum += myVector[k];

            k++;
        }
        cout << "Average with divisor " << j << " is " << stepSum / iterations << endl;
        j++;
        k = 0;
        stepSum = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you use a binary search then the max no of guesses should be `ceil(log2(n))`. For n = 10,000,000 this would be 24.

Comment: This isn't a C or C++ question, it is more in the pure math/statistics domain. Consider re-tagging?

Comment: Check the value of `RAND_MAX`. If it's less than half of your `MAX`, then dividing by a larger number would eliminate the first guess (or more), and could give a faster result.

Comment: .. which is 23.25, or ~23, so "22 guesses" is slightly off. It shows your calculations should be taken with a 6% grain of salt.

Comment: On Visual Studio [RAND_MAX is only 32767](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dfe3bzd.aspx) on [GCC it is 2147483647](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/ISO-Random.html)

Comment: When the divisor is greater than 2, the program "guesses" small numbers faster than it "guesses" large numbers. This makes your result very dependent on exactly which numbers you're "guessing".  (Note that your program is undefined since `half_search` doesn't return a value on all paths.)

Comment: @molbdnilo I think OP is measuring number of guesses, not speed.

Comment: It must be something about how the searched number is created: this are the results of calculate the average numbers of the search for all the numbers of the interval [1, 10.000.000] => 
2 22.3222786; 
3 24.1157581; 
4 26.9803124; 
5 30.1920943; 
...

Answer (score 1):

On some compilers (e.g Visual Studio 2013) `int n = rand() % MAX + 1;` will only provide a number between 1 and 32768 because `RAND_MAX` can be as low as 32767.

If your random number is quite small this will bias in favour of a larger divisor.

Consider using <[random](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)> in C++11 instead. Something like:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1, MAX);
//...
int n = dist(mt);
```

Answer (score 0):

The division by 2 would be always faster, and increment the performance, because it is easier for the CPU and takes less clock cycles. This is known as Binary Search. 
By using other divisor, you could have less "guesses" until the point that it has to ask to many times where the "secret" is greater or lower than the "guess".

Comment: And why would division by 2 always be faster?  Depending on the hardware, division by 4 might be just as fast, and there are no doubt systems on which it makes no difference what so ever.

Comment: Division by a power of 2 would be faster because it uses a shift operation which takes less clock cycles.

Comment: On some machines.  I've worked on a machine where division was faster than shifting, and on a high-end machine today, I would expect them to be about the same speed.

Answer (score 0):

I also see best result with divisor 2. This also should be the case  Because by using divisor 2 you are only employing binary search algorithm as each time your input set would be halved.